# Time complexity regarding linked_list ( Recursion )

Tags: python, performance, recursion, time, linked-list

let us say I have a recursive call for linked list: ( Singular )

```
def append(self, val):
    def append_rec(node, val):
        if node.next is None:
            node.next = Node(val)
        else:
            append_rec(node.next, val)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = Node(val)
        self.len += 1
    else:
        append_rec(self.head, val)
        self.len += 1
```

what is the time complexity of a recursive + linked list altogether?
I am at a little of problem of knowing how to find time complexity.
Please explain to me, thanks.

Comment: Can you limit your question to *one* question?

Comment: @trincot hi Yea, I removed the first, the second is one important, by the duplicates, I actually found it was like my code, the code isnt the same, but the meaning is same. I thought maybe my code could be o(n^2) or o(n), which is the reason I uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of calls of `append_rec` corresponds to the number of nodes that are already in the list.

All other steps in this code can be considered O(1) operations, so the total time complexity is linear to the number of nodes already in the list, i.e. O(n).

It may help to visualise the process. Let's say we already have a list with 2 nodes with values 1 and 2:

```
 self
  ↓
┌─────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ head: ─────►│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │
│ len:  2 │   │ next: ────────►│ next: None │
└─────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

Now let's say we call the method `append` with value 3, then first we get into the `else` block of `append` where `append_rec(self.head, val)` is called. Inside `append_rec` we have `node` referencing the first node now:

```
 self          node
  ↓             ↓
┌─────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ head: ─────►│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │
│ len:  2 │   │ next: ────────►│ next: None │
└─────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

The next action is a call of `append_rec(node.next, val)`. So now we have a *second* execution of `append_rec`, where also a `node` name exists. Let's give it an accent to distinguish it:

```
 self          node             node'
  ↓             ↓                ↓
┌─────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ head: ─────►│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │
│ len:  2 │   │ next: ────────►│ next: None │
└─────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

In this second execution of `append_rec`, there is no further recursive call made. Instead a node is created and the tail node's `next` attribute gets a reference to it:

```
 self          node             node'
  ↓             ↓                ↓
┌─────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ head: ─────►│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 3     │
│ len:  2 │   │ next: ────────►│ next: ────────►│ next: None │
└─────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

Once this is done, the second execution instance of `append_rec` returns, and the first execution instance has nothing more to do, so it also returns. And finally the `append` execution updates the `len` attribute and returns too.

```
 self
  ↓
┌─────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ head: ─────►│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 3     │
│ len:  3 │   │ next: ────────►│ next: ────────►│ next: None │
└─────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

I hope this illustrates how `append_rec` is called as many times as there are nodes in the list, and how the other actions have a constant time complexity.

Comment: WOW, thank you very much!!!!
its very good!
How did you do those squares? dont tell me you did it just for me, it seems like huge work

Comment: I have some of these figures in notepad++ and just copy and adjust.

Comment: ohh, nevertheless, huge thanks, it helped so much!!

Comment: @BenShaines [asciiflow](https://asciiflow.com/) is very helpful for ascii art like this

Comment: @Mulan oh cool, it actually copies that thing to keyboard.
Thanks :)